# ImportError while running python program

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have tried all the import methods and upgrading the libraries but still I'm unable to get over this error. I have downloaded and installed all the nltk and corpus data programmatically and it is working in the python shell but i'm getting error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spark.py", line 7, in <module>
    from textblob_aptagger import PerceptronTagger
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/textblob_aptagger/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from textblob_aptagger.taggers import PerceptronTagger
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/textblob_aptagger/taggers.py", line 10, in <module>
    from textblob.packages import nltk
ImportError: No module named packages
```

[Here](http://pastebin.com/evK1cKtd)'s a pastebin to my code and imports..

Comment: try import nltk instead

Comment: Already imported and it is working also

Comment: it obviously doesn't work? change `from textblob.packages import nltk` to only `import nltk`

Comment: Sorry but please check the pastebin link there is no such import in the code

Comment: sorry, didn't see your pastebin, next time include some code in your question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same error has been posted on github [here](https://github.com/sloria/textblob-aptagger/issues/5). Use this instead to install textblob:

```
$ pip install -U git+https://github.com/sloria/textblob-aptagger.git@dev
```

Also, you should change `from text.blob import TextBlob as tb`to `from textblob...`

Works for me..

Comment: I have already installed using this command also but still i'm getting the error.I read somehwhere that there is a directory problem in this , can you check ?

Comment: This is the most latest error that i'm getting  <br>Traceback (most recent call last):
  `File "spark.py", line 6, in <module>
    from text.blob import TextBlob as tb
ImportError: No module named text.blob`

Comment: did you change `from text.blob import TextBlob as tb` to `from textblob import TextBlob as tb`?